# Extract Data in Tabular format in NLTK

Tags: nltk

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag import pos_tag, map_tag
import re 

Text = open('aaa.txt')
t = Text.read()
print t
text = nltk.word_tokenize(t);
posTagged = pos_tag(text)
simpTags = [(word, map_tag('en-ptb','universal',tag)) for word,tag in posTagged]
sentence1 = simpTags
grammar1 = "NP: {<DET>?<ADJ>*<NOUN>}"
cp1 =  nltk.RegexpParser(grammar1)
result1 = cp1.parse(sentence1)
print result1
```

I want to extract entity relationships and this code is giving the output  accurately. What I want is to present it in a TABULAR format so that I can create a table in a database using the data. (Entity1, Relation, Entity2) coming in this format is enough for me. But I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: So you are trying to achieve entity relationship extraction by reformatting a parse tree, is this correct? If this is the case, can you give an example or two of the output you get and of the final format you want.

Comment: Suppose my text file contains: "My school is situated in New Delhi. The color of the sky is pink. I wonder why? 
I remembered a poem." I want the output in this way:(entity1,relattion,entity2)=[(my school,situated in, New Delhi),(the color,of,the sky),(the sky, is, pink).....]

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you are after. It seems that your goal is not very well defined. Your example looks a bit random – why is there `(the sky, is, pink)` rather than `(the color, is, pink)`, since "the color" is the head of the whole phrase "the color of the sky". And what triple would you want from a sentence like "He gave me a cookie"?

Comment: Sir, my aim is to extract the entity relationship. I want to extract the relationship and the two entities involved as a tuple of a table--not exactly the triple. For example, my school is situated in NY. So here school and NY are two entities (which are nothing but noun phrase(which only I need)) and their relationship is 'is situated in'.So I want to extract them so that I can a Database table where attributes are entity1,relationship, entiy2. The extracted data will be used as a value of each attribute.

Comment: "He gave me a cookie"- Here there is only one noun phrase (as I am not taking other than NP) 'a cookie'. So with one noun phrase there cant be a relationship, so we ignore the sentence.